# How to hook into creating a category?

Tags: categories, hooks

I want to do some stuff when a category is created the only hook i could find is

```
add_action( 'edited_category' , 'custom_term_saved', 10, 2 );
```

but it is only called on edit form saved not on create form saved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a hook that can be used for any taxonomy, `create_{$taxonomy}`, which in your case, is a category. So, it would be [`create_category`](http://hookr.io/actions/create_category/):

```
add_action( 'create_category', 'my_function', 10, 1 );
```

This is triggered by [`wp_insert_term()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_term/) at line 2142.